# Unity2d shooting object from different locations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity 2d and I have been following the tutorial about angry bird style game and I wanted to edit some gameplay of the game for my own project here is my problem when we shoot the object from the catapult I want to catch the object from a different location and then shoot the object again from that location I am working on a top-down 2d game that is like that shooting the object and catches it and then shoots again. here is my code most of it is like the tutorial and I kind of ruined the editing

public class firing : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float MaxStretch = 3f;
public LineRenderer CatapultFront;
public LineRenderer CatapultBack;
public Transform catapult;

private bool ClickedOn;
private Rigidbody2D Rigid;
private SpringJoint2D spring;
private Ray RayToMouse;
private Ray LeftCatapultToProjectile;
private Vector2 PreVelocity;
private float CircleRadius;
private float maxS;
private bool entering;




private void Awake()
{

    Rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    spring = GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>();



}


void Start () {

    catapult = spring.connectedBody.transform;
    LineRendereSetup();
    RayToMouse = new Ray(catapult.transform.position, Vector3.zero);
    LeftCatapultToProjectile = new Ray(CatapultFront.transform.position, Vector3.zero);
        maxS = MaxStretch * MaxStretch;

    CircleCollider2D circle = GetComponent<Collider2D>() as CircleCollider2D;
    CircleRadius = circle.radius;
  Rigid.gravityScale = 0.0f;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()


{
    LineRendererUpdate();
    if (ClickedOn)
        Dragging();
        if(spring.enabled==true)
        {

        if (!Rigid.isKinematic  &&  PreVelocity.sqrMagnitude > Rigid.velocity.sqrMagnitude) {

            spring.enabled = false;
                Rigid.velocity = PreVelocity;

            }
        if (!ClickedOn)
        {
          PreVelocity = Rigid.velocity;


            CatapultFront.enabled = false;
            CatapultBack.enabled = false;

        }

    }

}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
              spring.enabled = false;
        ClickedOn = true;
    }

private void OnMouseUp()
{



        spring.enabled = true;
        Rigid.isKinematic = false;
        ClickedOn = false;

}
protected void LineRendereSetup()
{
    CatapultFront.SetPosition(0, CatapultFront.transform.position);
    CatapultBack.SetPosition(0, CatapultBack.transform.position);

    CatapultFront.sortingLayerName = "foreground";
    CatapultBack.sortingLayerName = "foreground";

    CatapultFront.sortingOrder = 3;
    CatapultBack.sortingOrder = 1;

}
void Dragging()
{

    Vector3 mouseworldpoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 CatapultToMouse = mouseworldpoint - catapult.position;
    if(CatapultToMouse.sqrMagnitude > maxS)
    {
        RayToMouse.direction = CatapultToMouse;
        mouseworldpoint = RayToMouse.GetPoint(MaxStretch);

    }
    mouseworldpoint.z = 0f;
    transform.position = mouseworldpoint;
}
```

private  void LineRendererUpdate()
    {

```
    Vector2 CatapultToProjectile = transform.position - CatapultFront.transform.position;
    LeftCatapultToProjectile.direction = CatapultToProjectile;
    Vector2 HoldPoint = LeftCatapultToProjectile.GetPoint(CatapultToProjectile.magnitude +CircleRadius);
    CatapultFront.SetPosition(1,HoldPoint);
    CatapultBack.SetPosition(1, HoldPoint);
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    catapult.position = collision.transform.position;
    spring.connectedBody = null;
    spring.connectedBody = collision.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    OnMouseDown();
    OnMouseUp();

}
```

}

Comment: Explain what is your code actually doing, and be more concrete with your question, don't ask for "do for me that", try to be more concrete, like "I want to catch the object, but when I do that, the object (I don't know) jumps away".

Comment: I get that maybe a bit like a trampoline you want your object to bounce off again, however you havent explained how your code is not doing that, or what it does,etc.